# Error in arima of R: too few non-missing observations

Tags: r, forecasting

I am using `arima()` and `auto.arima()` of R to get the prediction of sales. The data is at week level for three years.

my code looks like:

`x<-c(1571,1501,895,1335,2306,930,2850,1380,975,1080,990,765,615,585,838,555,1449,615,705,465,165,630,330,825,555,720,615,360,765,1080,825,525,885,507,884,1230,342,615,1161,
1585,723,390,690,993,1025,1515,903,990,1510,1638,1461.67,1082,1075,2315,1014,2140,1572,794,1363,1184,1248,1344,1056,816,720,896,608,624,560,512,304,640,640,704,1072,768,
816,640,272,1168,736,1003,864,658.67,768,841,1727,944,848,432,704,850.67,1205,592,1104,976,629,814,1626,933.33,1100.33,1730,2742,1552,1038,826,1888,1440,1372,824,1824,1392,1424,768,464,
960,320,384,512,478,1488,384,338.67,176,624,464,528,592,288,544,418.67,336,752,400,1232,477.67,416,810.67,1256,1040,823,240,1422,704,718,1193,1541,1008,640,752,
1008,864,1507,4123,2176,899,1717,935)`

`length_data<-length(x)`

`length_train<-round(length_data*0.80)`

`forecast_period<-length_data-length_train`

`train_data<-x[1:length_train]`

`train_data<-ts(train_data,frequency=52,start=c(1,1))`

`validation_data<-x[(length_train+1):length_data]`

`validation_data<-ts(validation_data,frequency=52,start=c(ceiling((length_train)/52),((length_train)%%52+1)))`

`arima_output<-auto.arima(train_data) # fit the ARIMA Model`

`arima_validate <- Arima(x=validation_data,model=arima_output)`

Error:

`Error in stats::arima(x = x, order = order, seasonal = seasonal, include.mean = include.mean,  :`

`too few non-missing observations`

What I am doing wrong?
What does it mean by "too few non-missing observations"? I have searched it now net, but did not get any better explanation.

Thanks for any kind of help!

Comment: Have you read the comments to [your post at CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/126624/error-in-arima-of-r-too-few-non-missing-observations)?

Comment: I have modified the question. I hope I have covered the required/relevant information. Let me know if I am missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arima_output` is a *seasonal* ARIMA model:

```
> arima_output
Series: train_data 
ARIMA(1,0,1)(0,1,0)[52]
```

`Arima()` then attempts to refit this particular model to `validation_data`. But to fit a seasonal model to a time series, you need at least one full year of observations, since seasonal ARIMA depends on seasonal differencing.

As an illustration, note that `Arima()` will happily and without errors refit a time series that is double as long as `validation_data`:

```
validation_data <- x[(length_train+1):length_data]
validation_data<-ts(rep(validation_data,2),frequency=52,
  start=c(ceiling((length_train)/52),((length_train)%%52+1)))
arima_validate <- Arima(x=validation_data,model=arima_output)
```

One way of dealing with this would be to force `auto.arima()` to use a nonseasonal model, by specifying `D=0`:

```
validation_data <- x[(length_train+1):length_data]
validation_data<-ts(validation_data,frequency=52,
  start=c(ceiling((length_train)/52),((length_train)%%52+1)))
arima_output<-auto.arima(train_data, D=0) # fit the ARIMA Model
arima_validate <- Arima(x=validation_data,model=arima_output)
```

So this *did* turn out to be more of a CrossValidated question...

Comment: Thanks Stephan...from next time I will take care of this and thanks for your response...

Answer (score 1):

Your chosen model is ARIMA(1,0,1)(0,1,0)[52]. That is, it has a seasonal difference of lag 52. Your validation data has 32 observations. So you cannot take the seasonal differences on the validation data without knowing what the training data is.

One way around this is to fit the model to the full time series, and then extract what you want (presumably residuals from the validation portion).

You can also improve the readability of your code:

```
x <- ts(x, frequency=52, start=c(1,1))
length_data <- length(x)
length_train <- round(length_data*0.80)
train_data <- ts(head(x, length_train), 
                  frequency=frequency(x), start=start(x))
validation_data <- ts(tail(x, length_data-length_train), 
                  frequency=frequency(x), end=end(x))

library(forecast)
arima_train <- auto.arima(train_data) 
arima_full <- Arima(x, model=arima_train)
res <- window(residuals(arima_full), start=start(validation_data))
```